# gradle doesn't work in Intellij - problems with JAVA_HOME

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

- I can run gradle from a command line to see its version.
- I can run, compile and debug a grails app in IntelliJ (version 10.0 or version 10.2)
- I installed the IntelliJ Gradle Plugin.

Whenever I try to do anything with gradle from within Intellij I get an error as follows:

```
Executing command: "tasks"
Failed to connect to gradle process for command 'tasks'

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.0\jre

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

But in my environment I have `JAVA_HOME` set to the proper JDK in a different directory. Plus when I look in IntelliJ for the project, it also shows the JDK in the proper JDK location.  I cannot find anything that attempts to point the JDK to the Intellij JRE location.

Any ideas please?

Comment: What do you mean by IntelliJ Gradle plugin? Isn't it bundled? Where did you take it from to install?

Comment: I think it's the Gradle GUI plugin.

Comment: I posted an answer here if it helps anyone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54525381/674669

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IntelliJ uses its own jre.

to force IntelliJ to use it, you need to set the environment variable `IDEA_JDK` to point to your JDK.

then simply restart intellij and gradle gui plugin should now work.

Comment: This sounds promising.  Thanks.

Comment: Does not work.  Gradle from Intellij still attempts to use an old path even with JAVA_HOME and IDEA_JDK pointing to the correct place.

Comment: Adding **BOTH** `IDEA_JDK` and `JAVA_HOME` as environment variables, both pointing to the JDK, works.

Comment: Doing this and deleting and recreating my run configuration made it work for me.

Comment: in addition to what Simon said, you need go to gradle setting page and choose `JAVA_HOME` as what gradle should use

Comment: Each time I use JetBrains products they just make me mad. ( Better use VS Code less automation more freedom less pain more fun.

Answer (score 12):

Man I had so much trouble with this as well, and I don't remember having this much trouble before. I think they changed something. Here are the incantations which got it working for me on Mac OS X 10.11.5, both with Java and Gradle on IntelliJ 2016.1

Here's the summary: install the latest Java JDK from Oracle, add the java_home value to $JAVA_HOME and set that value to $IDEA_HOME (IntelliJ's variable for defining which JDK to use), install gradle (optional) using homebrew, then define the project SDK in IntelliJ.

Here it is broken down from the very beginning of a clean install:

#### 1. Download Java from [Oracle's Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

#### 2. Use homebrew to install gradle

IntelliJ ships with its own version of Gradle, so this is really optional, and is helpful if you want to use Gradle outside of IntelliJ.

```
`brew update && brew install gradle`
```

#### 3. Set the env variables

Paste the following into `~/.profile`. These values will work regardless of which version of java or gradle you have installed. Don't set the GRADLE_HOME if you didn't install the standalone gradle.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export IDEA_JDK=$JAVA_HOME
export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec
```

#### 4. Set the environment variable to occur at application launch so that IntelliJ sees is using OS X's `launchctl` program:

```
launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

#### 5. Define the project SDK

Use the project settings window in IntelliJ to define the project SDK (I don't see this option anywhere else in the global IntelliJ preferences window, this has to be done in the project settings).

[image: Project Settings]

#### 6. Wait for the indexes to update, then close and re-open IntelliJ. You should now be able to build the program.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Intellij version 10.x you should not install any Plugin to run a gradle script.

All you have to do is to go to the Gradle setup (`File -> Settings -> Gradle`) and set the Gradle Home folder (the location of your Gradle installation, eg. C:\tools\gradle).

You should be able to select a Gradle build file and run it.

Comment: Hello Luciano, I've done this, but I guess there is no real built in support.  Is that right?  I don't see any menu items that have anything to do with gradle.

Comment: you can vote here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-53476?projectKey=IDEA to ask for "official" support

Answer (score 4):

Point your JAVA_HOME to JDK, not to JRE.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error might be caused by an install bug with IntelliJ IDEA. When I look at the installed folder referred to in the error message on my filesystem:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.0\jre
```

I see the jre folder but then another jre folder beneath that one which contains the bin and lib folders of the jre:

```
jre
    jre
        bin
        lib
```

I copied bin and lib up a level into the first jre folder, and that fixed this error for me.