# Gradle home cannot be found on Mac

Tags: java, bash, macos, gradle

I've installed `gradle` on MAC using terminal.

`brew install gradle`

Gradle has been installed successfully.

```
gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-01-03 15:31:04 UTC
Revision:     075893a3d0798c0c1f322899b41ceca82e4e134b

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_112 (Oracle Corporation 25.112-b16)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.3 x86_64
```

but I can not find gradle home.

```
echo $GRADLE_HOME
[empty result]
```

the first step to determine home directory is detect location of `gradle` instruction:

```
which gradle
/usr/local/bin/gradle
```

there is incomprehensible bash file.

---

Any ideas how to detect gradle home directory via terminal?

Comment: I would guess that either you don't need `$GRADLE_HOME` because gradle uses a sensible default, or `brew` has put `GRADLE_HOME` in a login script. Try logging out and back in.

Comment: `brew info gradle`

Comment: @slim, completely agree. I do not need to set up `$GRADLE_HOME`. But I need how to detect one because of some IDE wants me to define correspond path in configuration.

Comment: @oliver-charlesworth, it really works for me. I've run the command and got good enough information about installed `gradle` (home directory also).

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495474/how-to-define-gradles-home-in-idea

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use command:

```
brew info gradle
```

As the result you will have something like this:

```
gradle: stable 4.0.1
Build system based on the Groovy language
https://www.gradle.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/3.4 (181 files, 74.5MB) *
  Built from source on 2017-02-24 at 15:01:34
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gradle.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java >= 1.7 ✔
==> Options
--with-all
    Installs Javadoc, examples, and source in addition to the binaries
```

Here, on the line 4 you can see the home path : `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/3.4`

Answer (score 31):

You can retrieve the path for `GRADLE_HOME` automatically using the following snippet in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=$(brew info gradle | grep /usr/local/Cellar/gradle | awk '{print $1}')
```

This is handy when the path to Gradle's home changes, when Gradle is updated.

Comment: If there are multiple versions installed, the above will grab the first version in the list.  If you want the current version in use (marked with an asterisk * at the end), try this instead:  brew info gradle | sed -nE 's#^(/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/[^ ]+).+\*#\1#p'

Comment: It is worth mentioning that adding this into your bash profile file will slowdown shell initialisation because `brew info gradle` actually takes some time.

Answer (score 28):

On Mojave (v10.14), Gradle v5.4, I had to append `libexec` after Gradle version for IntelliJ to work.

```sh
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.4/libexec
```

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: This worked for me on a mac after running `brew info gradle`

Answer (score 10):

I've gradle installed When using homebrew, below one failed with me, and kept telling undefined:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/<version>
```

The below symlink worked perfectly, and solved my issue:

```
/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec
```

Answer (score 8):

"brew info gradle" command not always give the installed path

```
br*ew info gradle
gradle: stable 5.6.3
Open-source build automation tool based on the Groovy and Kotlin DSL
https://www.gradle.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gradle.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java >= 1.8 ✔
==> Analytics
install: 29,106 (30 days), 144,607 (90 days), 611,211 (365 days)
install_on_request: 28,237 (30 days), 137,584 (90 days), 577,691 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)*
```

Answer (score 3):

On Mojave, Gradle v6.6, I appended libexec after Gradle version for IntelliJ to work.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.4/libexec
```

Answer (score 1):

My point isn't enough for commenting on flic's answer in the previous post.
If it happens to be in MacOS, the asterisk should be escaped as:

```
brew info gradle | sed -nE 's#^(/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/[^ ]+).+\*#\1#p'
```

or there will be `sed: 1: "s#^(/usr/local/Cellar/g ...`: RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid" error reported.

Answer (score 0):

add following in **~/.bash_profile**

```
export GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle-8.6"
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Run, `source ~/.bash_profile`. 
And run a `gradle -v`