# How do I know if Gradle is installed on my machine?

Tags: gradle

I have a Macbook with Android Studio installed. Since I have projects that use Gradle (and Android Studio also uses Gradle), I would assume I have Gradle installed on my machine somewhere. However if I type `gradle` into the terminal I get `command not found`. So, do I have Gradle automatically installed because I have Android Studio, or do I have to run `brew install gradle` ?

I know this is a bad/silly question, but I just want to make sure I don't install Gradle twice.

Comment: Well-behaved projects use the gradle wrapper. So you don't need to install gradle: the gradle wrapper downloads and uses it for you. https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to install Gradle at all.  The projects are likely using the [Gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) - i.e. you should just be able to run `./gradlew whatever` inside their root directories.

In the unlikely case that they're **not** using the wrapper, then `brew install gradle` ought to work on a Mac.

(I don't know anything about whether Android Studio deploys Gradle, but if it does, clearly it does so in a way that doesn't play well with your `PATH`.)

Comment: If I type `./gradlew` in the terminal at my root directory, i get `Permission denied`. How can I fix this? Edit: I solved it by cmod-ing it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: According to a warning I just got using [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/), Gradle wrapper requires an internet connection. So if there are ever times when you might need to use Gradle without internet access, then that might be a case for installing it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer can be found here: [Gradle home cannot be found on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367082/gradle-home-cannot-be-found-on-mac).

> Command: `brew info gradle`
>
> As the result you will have something like this:
>
> ```
> gradle: stable 4.0.1
> Build system based on the Groovy language
> https://www.gradle.org/
> /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/3.4 (181 files, 74.5MB) *
> Built from source on 2017-02-24 at 15:01:34
> From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-        core/blob/master/Formula/gradle.rb
> ==> Requirements
> Required: java >= 1.7 ✔
> ==> Options
> --with-all
> Installs Javadoc, examples, and source in addition to the binaries
> ```
>
> Here, on the line 4 you can see the home path: `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/3.4`