# How to know the exact program path or name that executes gradle script?

Tags: gradle

I've a gradle script, which can be run with either `gradle`, `gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` on Windows. But how to know the exact program path or name that executes gradle script.
Is there anything similar to `argv[0]` in c?

Comment: `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` are the recommended way to run the scripts since they can handle the download of the Gradle version defined when they were created. This will ensure that the same version will be used by all who use this script. The scripts will use the gradle command, but it should be the one for the version defined in the script file, not necessarily the one found in the path. If you are doing a test project, you can use `gradle`. Why would you want to know how is the script invoked?

Comment: I want to write a gradle script that works on different os. And in this script, it will call other gradle task, also I can print help message like a cli if there are some errors occurred.