# Apply plugin from a local location

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I am using org.ajoberstar.grgit in my module level build.gradle like this:

```
plugins {
  id "org.ajoberstar.grgit" version "1.5.0"
}

ext {
  Grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit
}
// Some more code
```

My top-level build.gradle looks like this:

```
subprojects {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  apply plugin: 'java'

  apply plugin: 'eclipse'

  apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```

The build is executed properly. If I execute it for the first time, it downloads the required files from https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/. I guess this information is coming from the plugin block in the module level build.gradle and download is facilitated by the mavenCentral() command. Also, the files get saved in ~/.gradle/caches/3.4.1 and for subsequent builds, the IDE(Intellij IDEA) uses this location only. My question is that can I download the files to some other places manually and then make the IDE to pick up them from that location?

Comment: Let me know if this works add following into your settings.gradle file `buildCache {
    local {
        // Set local build cache directory.
        directory = "${settingsDir}/build-cache"
    }
}`

Comment: It did not work. It gave following error: `Could not find method buildCache() for arguments [settings_8vf83wfau80qqvi5syqks94zv$_run_closure1@5eb3e372] on settings 'java' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.`

Comment: on settings.gradle `pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()

    }
}` ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories, along with 1 above changes

Comment: It did not work either. It failed with the following error: `Could not find method pluginManagement()`

Comment: My gradle is 3.4.1. I guess this is too old?

Comment: sorry for trial and error: `$gradle -g /some/other/dir build`, ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html

Comment: you can change GRADLE_HOME in intelliJ idea as shown in image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120932/2987755

Comment: I think pluginManagement is not present in 3.4.1. I will upgrade it to 5.0.+ and see if it works then.

Comment: you can ignor `pluginManagement()` changes for $gradle -g /some/other/dir build and give it a try