# Force Idea to use Gradle "specific location" by default

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea uses `'gradle-wrapper.properties' file` as default Gradle location for all imported Gradle projects:

[image]

I want to use `Specified location` for imported Gradle projects by default:

[image]

However, it's impossible to choose `Specified location` as default option.

How to force Idea to use `Specified location` for new importing projects?

Linked:

- [IDEA and how to disable gradle wrapper generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462253/idea-and-how-to-disable-gradle-wrapper-generation)
- [Use local gradle distribution instead of wrapper for new projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491530/use-local-gradle-distribution-instead-of-wrapper-for-new-projects)

Comment: Btw why do you want to always use a specific local version?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to change this setting for all projects. Please vote for this request: [IDEA-215792](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215792) Ability to choose Gradle when creating new project

Comment: Voted for the request. Thank you!