# Gradle '*' project refresh failed... No signature... blah blah ... looks like it's using jdk1.6 not 1.7. how do i change it?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am attempting to resynchronize my projects with intellij idea. When it gets to compiling buildSrc, I get this error:

```
Gradle 'myproject' project refresh failed:
Error:No signature of method: java.lang.ProcessBuilder.inheritIO() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] 
Possible solutions: inheritIO(), iterator()
```

It looks like intellij is a little confused.

Could this be because the JAVA_HOME variable is set to jdk1.6? I would like to determine a solution to the problem with having to change this variable. I.e. if i could control the jdk used by gradle from within intellij, could someone point it out for me?

I have attempted to set the 'org.gradle.java.home' variable in the gradle.properties to jdk1.7, I've also tried setting GRADLE_OPTS=-Dorg.gradle.java.home=\Path\to\jdk1.7

also I've tried setting the IDEA_JDK to 1.7 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124368/gradle-doesnt-work-in-intellij-problems-with-java-home?rq=1)

I am using Intellij EAP 13.1 v135.815

Comment: If this was a JDK 1.6/1.7 problem, it would probably not print `Possible solutions: inheritIO()`. Do you have proof that the `buildSrc` code to be compiled is correct?

Comment: yes, I have tried to set the JAVA_HOME to jdk 1.7.0 and when i do, It successfully compiles and resyncs

Comment: I don't see an IntelliJ option to set a Gradle JDK, so there may not be a better way. Typically what counts is which JDK is on your PATH.